# Docker compose apache to php-fpm DNS lookup failure

Tags: php, docker, apache, docker-compose

I'm building a php web app using docker compose - one container for apache and the other for php-fpm. The DB will be accessed via a different connection. The part that's giving me trouble is trying to connect to the php container via the apache container when php code needs to be run. When I navigate to say http://localhost:8000/script.php, I get the following in my apache error log:

```
[proxy:debug] mod_proxy.c(1506): AH01143: Running scheme fcgi handler (attempt 0), referer: localhost:8080/application.html
[proxy_fcgi:debug] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(1054): AH01076: url: fcgi://php:9000/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/script.php proxyname: (null) proxyport: 0, referer: localhost:8080/application.html
[proxy_fcgi:debug] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(1063): AH01078: serving URL fcgi://php:9000/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/script.php, referer: localhost:8080/application.html
[proxy:debug] proxy_util.c(2538): AH00942: FCGI: has acquired connection for (*:80)
[proxy:debug] proxy_util.c(2596): AH00944: connecting fcgi://php:9000/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/script.php to php:9000, referer: localhost:8080/application.html
[proxy:error] AH00898: DNS lookup failure for: php returned by /script.php, referer: localhost:8080/application.html
[proxy:debug] proxy_util.c(2554): AH00943: FCGI: has released connection for (*:80)
```

Notice the error, `DNS lookup failure for: php returned by /script.php`

The compose file I have looks like:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  apache:
    build: 
      args:
        DBHOST: ${DBHOST} 
        DBPORT: ${DBPORT} 
        DBNAME: ${DBNAME} 
        DBUSER: ${DBUSER} 
        DBPASSWORD: ${DBPASSWORD} 
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./path/to/Dockerfile
    links:
      - php
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
  php:
    build: 
      args: 
          DBHOST: ${DBHOST} 
          DBPORT: ${DBPORT} 
          DBNAME: ${DBNAME} 
          DBUSER: ${DBUSER} 
          DBPASSWORD: ${DBPASSWORD} 
      dockerfile: ./path/to/Dockerfile
    context: .
    expose:
      - "9000"
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
```

My apache docker file uses httpd:2.4. I read before that the files should also be accessible in the PHP container, so I add them in the PHP dockerfile (in addition to being on the apache container). I have some confusion as to where they should exactly be, so I added them to a few places. The PHP docker file looks like

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm
ARG DBHOST
ARG DBPORT
ARG DBNAME
ARG DBUSER
ARG DBPASSWORD
ENV DBHOST $DBHOST
ENV DBPORT $DBPORT
ENV DBNAME $DBNAME
ENV DBUSER $DBUSER
ENV DBPASSWORD $DBPASSWORD
RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y libpq-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-configure pgsql -with-pgsql=/usr/local/pgsql \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_pgsql pgsql

# I don't know exactly where they should be, so I copied the files to different locations and none solve 
# the error I'm getting
COPY . /var/www/html
COPY . /
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
COPY . /usr/local/apache2/htdocs

COPY ./htdocs/ /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
COPY ./htdocs/ /
COPY ./htdocs/ /var/www/html
```

Finally, I have the following in my apache conf file

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://php:9000"
</FilesMatch>
```

Is there a simple fix I've overlooked/haven't seen?

Comment: `links:` and `expose:` are obsolete options from first-generation Docker networking.  That's _probably_ not your problem, but does deleting these help at all?  If you check with `docker-compose ps`, is the `php` container still running?

Comment: Removing the links and expose keys from the compose file did not fix it, but thanks for the info

Comment: The php container is still running. Seems like there are no inherent issues on it being able to run but somehow it cannot be connected to